# dict_values intersection and hashable types

Tags: python, dictionary, intersection, hashset

I would like to check the intersection of two dictionaries.  If I do this, I get exactly what I expected:

```
dict1 = {'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':3}
dict2 = {'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':4}

set(dict1.items()).intersection(dict2.items())
>> {('x', 1), ('y', 2)}
```

However, if the items *within* the dictionary are nonhashable, I get an error.

```
dict1 = {'x':{1,2}, 'y':{2,3}, 'z':3}
dict2 = {'x':{1,3}, 'y':{2,4}, 'z':4}  

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-56-33fdb931ef54> in <module>
 ----> 1 set(dict1.items()).intersection(dict2.items())

TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Of course, I get the same error for tuples and lists, as they are also not hashable.

Is there a work around or an existing class I can use to check the intersection of nonhashable dictionary values?

Comment: x y and z represent some kind of points?

Comment: no, that's just representative data.  the actual case is totally different but it shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: @Prune The question you linked to is not for unhashable dict values, which the OP specifically wants to address.

Comment: The accepted answer is for hashable items; other answers deal with the unhashable.

Comment: @Prune I see. I did not notice the other answer that addresses the unhashable, but it's a rather bad answer since it costs *O(n ^ 2)* in time complexity when a proper solution should do it in linear time.

Comment: That's going to be hard with unhashable elements; **O(N)** time generally hinges upon an **O(1)** lookup.  You *could* coerce each element to a hashable type and then do the natural intersection, but this question seems to be headed a different direction.  Lower complexity is not always the most efficient solution.

Comment: @Prune I don't see why you say "this question seems to be headed a different direction". What in the question makes you think coercing each element into a hashable type isn't a solution for the question?

Comment: OP specified intersection of nonhashable values, in the final sentence.
Also, coercing to a hashable value is a readily available solution OP passed up.  Maybe that's not as "obvious" to OP, and is an acceptable solution.  Todd?

Comment: @Prune Where in the question do you see that the OP has attempted or passed up a solution that coerces values to hashable ones? The last sentence is exactly the point of coercion so I'm not sure what point you're trying to make by bringing up the last sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a "makeHashable" function to apply to dictionary items for comparison purposed and used it to build a set that you can then check in a list comprehension:

```
dict1 = {'x':{1,2}, 'y':{2,3}, 'z':3}
dict2 = {'x':{1,3}, 'y':{3,2}, 'z':4}

def makeHashable(x):
    if isinstance(x,(list,tuple)):  return tuple(map(makeHashable,x))
    if isinstance(x,set):           return makeHashable(sorted(x))
    if isinstance(x,dict):          return tuple(map(makeHashable,x.items()))
    return x

dict1Set  = set(map(makeHashable,dict1.items()))
intersect = [ kv for kv in dict2.items() if makeHashable(kv) in dict1Set]
```

output:

```
print(intersect) 

# [('y', {2, 3})]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.8/bin/python3


def intersection1(dict1, dict2):
    intersection = set(dict1.items()).intersection(dict2.items())
    return intersection


def intersection2(dict1, dict2):
    result = {}
    for key1 in dict1:
        if key1 in dict2 and dict1[key1] == dict2[key1]:
            result[key1] = dict1[key1]
    return result


def main():
    dict1 = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
    dict2 = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 4}

    print(intersection2(dict1, dict2))
    print(intersection1(dict1, dict2))
    # >> {('x', 1), ('y', 2)}

    dict3 = {'x': [1, 2], 'y': [2, 3], 'z': [3, 4]}
    dict4 = {'x': [1, 2], 'y': [2, 3], 'z': [4, 5]}

    print(intersection2(dict3, dict4))
    print(intersection1(dict3, dict4))


main()
```

You of course cannot put an unhashable type in a set, so I've done the next best thing with intersection2()

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize the dict values before performing set intersection, and deserialize the values in the resulting set. The following example uses `pickle` for serialization:

```
import pickle

{k: pickle.loads(v) for k, v in set.intersection(
    *({(k, pickle.dumps(v)) for k, v in i} for i in map(dict.items, (dict1, dict2))))}
```

so that given:

```
dict1 = {'x': {1, 2}, 'y': {2, 3}, 'z': 3}
dict2 = {'x': {2, 1}, 'y': {2, 4}, 'z': 4}
```

the expression would return:

```
{'x': {1, 2}}
```